# How to keep random.choice() from rechecking itself

Tags: python, function

Today I was writing a code in which it would give you addition or subtraction of integer problems. For example:

```
from random import randint, choice
while True:
        value_1 = randint(-9,9)
        value_2 = randint(-9,9)
        lol = choice(['+', '-'])
        number = input("What is %s %s %s" % (value_1, lol, value_2))
        if lol == "+":
            try:
                number_x = int(number)
            except ValueError:
                 print("You did not enter a number silly goose")
            else:
                if number_x == value_1 + value_2:
                    print("You got the answer right. Good job!!")
                else:
                    print("Incorrecto my padwan. You still have much to learn")
        elif lol == "-":
            try:
                number_x = int(number)
            except ValueError:
                print("You did not enter a number silly goose")
            else:
                if number_x == value_1 - value_2:
                    print("You got the answer right. Good job!!")
                else:
                    print("Incorrecto my padwan. You still have much to learn")
        else:
            print("How did u even do this")
```

The issue is that when the choice() function chooses "+" or "-", instead of adding or subtracting like I want it when checking if the person got the answer correct, it rechecks the choice function. This means that even if the computer asks the person "what is 9 - 8", it rechecks lol. So instead of checking to see if the person got the answer to 9-8, the computer sometimes checks to see if the person got the right answer to 9+8. What I want to do here is after the choice() function is checked the first time, it keeps the output, so it does not recheck choice after the computer asks the question to person originally. Or is there an easier way to write this that outputs the same thing I am asking? By the way sorry for the question being written so confusedly and if the answer is obvious(I'm new to programming)

Comment: Looks like the program is actually working. While the `input` opens up a dialog, the output of your prints are going to the console, that's what might be confusing you. I have run it and can see the correct messages being printed.

This at least if you run the script on Windows, using PythonWin. If you run it from a terminal (cmd on windows) you should see more clearly the behavior.

Comment: I don't see a problem in the program either. (I also don't know what's being talked about with the dialog here). It all looks fine to me.

Comment: @ Score_Under I am referring to this http://snag.gy/nWmdw.jpg I am though making an assumption that needs to be confirmed or dismissed...

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @Evert The code works fine for me on both. The only things here which are different in python 2 are the print statements and the input function, but the print statements are bracketed and the result of the input function is always coerced to int, so assuming the user's input is well-formed the program will behave the same in python 2 as it does in python 3.

Comment: @Score_Under True, I had overlooked that `input()` in Python 2 can sometimes produce the correct result anyway. I assume though that this is Python 3.

Comment: you want that `lol` only be reset under certain conditions?? if so, you can put some initial value to it before the loop and change its value when the condition is meet

Comment: Can you run the program a few times and then give us an example where the program does things backwards? it could be your math that's the problem. For instance, `-9 - -6` is `-3` but if you didn't do the math right, you might think that its not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a different approach. Here is mine for your reference:

```
import random

op1, op2 = ['', '-'], ['+', '-']
nums = list('0123456789')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        question = ''.join([ random.choice(i) for i in (op1, nums, op2, nums) ])
        print 'Q: ' +  question + ' =',
        answer = raw_input()
        if answer == 'q':
            print 'Bye'
            break
        elif not answer.lstrip('-').isdigit():
            print '%s is not a valid answer\n' % (answer)
        elif int(answer) == eval(question):
            print 'Good Job\n'
        else: print 'Try again\n'
```

Sample output:

```
Q: -9+6 = 3
Try again

Q: 0-6 = -6
Good Job

Q: -3+3 = E
E is not a valid answer

Q: 1-2 = q
Bye
```